# how can I output with additional information in a specific row in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

For example: there is a lot of food stored in the database in this format:

```
kind      | name
----------+----------
fruit     | apple
fruit     | banana
vegetable | lettuce
vegetable | onion
```

I want to select all vegetables and add a tag behind them like:

```
apple
banana
lettuce (vegetable)
onion (vegetable)
```

I can use `SELECT` to select all vegetables:

```
SELECT name 
FROM "food" 
WHERE kind LIKE "vegetable";
```

But how can I add a tag behind the vegetable?

Hope someone can give me a hint

Comment: Why not just pull the kind field as well?

Comment: Your example list includes fruits but you say "*I want to select all vegetables*". So should fruits be included?

Answer (score 2):

In SQLite you have to use the `||` operator:

```sql
SELECT name || ' (' || kind || ')' FROM food WHERE kind like 'vegetable';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `CASE` expression for the vegetables:

```
SELECT name ||
       CASE 
         WHEN kind = 'vegetable' THEN ' (' || kind || ')' 
         ELSE '' 
       END AS name 
FROM food;
```

Answer (score -1):

My basic answer would be to use Concat:
`SELECT CONCAT(name," (", kind, ")") FROM "food" WHERE kind like "vegetable";`

Comment: There is no CONCAT() function in SQLite

Comment: He asked for sql though